# Runing PHP code on click of Google map marker

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Guys below is my php code:

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://192.168.1.220/cgi-bin/handle_login.tcl");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                "user=admin&pw=admin&submit=Login&sid=' '");        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $response=curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$response');</script>"."<br/>";
    echo strpos("$response","sid")."<br/>";
    echo strstr($response, 'sid')."<br/>";
    echo substr($response,90,19)."<br/>";
    //$_SESSION['value'] = $response;
    curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

**I need to execute above code and print its content as output when user click google map marker.**

**Is it possible exceute the above code?**

Comment: Yeah find the click event of marker. And make ajax call and put these code in that ajax call.

Comment: @Bhavin..Thanks a lot man..Totally forgot about ajax..

Comment: try to get click event of marker and then do an ajax call to a php page where this curl code will going to execute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `addDomListener` to click event like this:

```
function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        });

        // We add a DOM event here to show an alert if the DIV containing the
        // map is clicked.
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(mapDiv, 'click', function() {
          window.alert('Map was clicked!');
          // make ajax call here
        });
      }
```

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1) First of all find click event of marker. You can find it on this document. 
link :- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple.

2) Then make ajax call and put the above `PHP Code` in the file on which you are doing ajax call.

You can find click event of marker using below function.

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53, -1.33);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:myCenter,
    url: '/',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
});

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom: 14,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.location.href = marker.url;});
```

Put one division so through this demo you can get click event :-

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```